# How to view all Feature Flags in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, feature-flags

I have added feature flags in my django using package django-waffle. I defined a switch in django admin panel. The default Switch model provides all the necessary functionality.To list all the switches using manage.py, we use this command:

```
./manage.py waffle_switch -l
```

How to list all the switches in views.py?

Comment: You seem to be using some package which is not builtin to Django. If you are asking questions about a third party package please specify the package you are using in the question. Please [edit]] your question and clarify. I am assuming you are using this package: [django-waffle](https://waffle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: yes I am using django-waffle.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work for `switches`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from waffle import get_waffle_switch_model


def index(request):
    switches = get_waffle_switch_model().get_all()
    switch_values = [(f.name, f.is_active(request)) for f in switches]

    return HttpResponse(switch_values)
```

and for `feature flags` pretty similar:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from waffle import get_waffle_flag_model

def index(request):
    flags = get_waffle_flag_model().get_all()
    flag_values = [(f.name, f.is_active(request)) for f in flags]

    return HttpResponse(flag_values)
```